# Migrating a Rails ActiveRecord column to a new model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have a table called `Domain_Data` which has a unique string column called `domain`.  Because many things need to point to domain throughout my app, I'm going to be seperating `Domain` to its own seperate model.  In `Domain_Data` I want to replace the `domain` column with a foreign key pointer to the `Domain.id`.  The tricky part is updating the data itself, so that the domain strings are in `Domain`, and the `id` pointers are in `Domain_Data`.

I'm well aware of how I could do a migration like this in pure SQL, but I'm wondering what the "Railsy" way is to make a migration like this.  Can it all be done through migrations, or should some of it be done manually through rake tasks and the like?

I'm a Rails newb, looking for the canonical way to do a migration like this.  Using Rails 2.3

Answer (score 0):

You will run into some namespace issues as your new domain association will need to do some renaming.
Migrations can also run ruby code, so your migration(s) could look something like this

The follow is the *general* code needed.

```
 # First Migration to rename the domain field
    def RenameDomainField < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        rename_column :domain_datas, :domain, :domain_name
      end

      def self.down
        #code for opposite of up
      end

    end


    # Second Migration to add the Domain model
    def CreateDomains < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        create_table :domain do |t|
          t.string :domain_name
        end
      end

      def self.down
        #code for opposite of up
      end

    end

    #Create a new relationship:
    def DomainData < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :domain
    end


    # A third migration to move the data over
    def RefactorDomainData < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        #Add the new forgein key
        add_column :domain_datas, :domain_id, :integer

        #create the new domain records and link them
        DomainData.all do |domain_data|
          domain_data.create_domain(:domain_name => domain_data.domain_name)
        end

        #trash the old column
        remove_column :domain_datas, :domain_name
      end

      def self.down
        #code for opposite of up
      end

    end
```